# C++ sockets: accept() hangs when client calls connect(), but accept() responds to HTTP GET request

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I'm trying to write a demo server/client program in C++. I first ran my server program on my Macbook, with ngrok on and forwarding a public address on the Internet to a local address on my machine. I'm seeing something that I don't understand when I try to run my client program to connect to the server:

1. If the client tries to connect to localhost at the local port defined in the server program, the server accepts as expected and the client successfully connects,
2. If the client tries to connect to the ngrok server address at port 80 (default for ngrok), then the client connects, but the server is still blocked at the accept call. (This I don't understand!)
3. If I send an HTTP GET request to the ngrok server address, the server successfully accepts the connection.

Why do I see these? In the ideal case, I want my server to accept connections from my client program, not just respond to the HTTP GET request.

Here's my code if that helps: For the client,

```
#include "helpers.hh"
#include <cstdio>
#include <netdb.h>

// usage: -h [host] -p [port]
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const char* host = "x.xx.xx.xx"; // use the server's ip here.
    const char* port = "80";

    // parse arguments
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "h:p:")) >= 0) {
        if (opt == 'h') {
            host = optarg;
        } else if (opt == 'p') {
            port = optarg;
        }
    }

    // look up host and port
    struct addrinfo hints, *ais;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;        // use IPv4 or IPv6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    // use TCP
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV;
    if (strcmp(host, "ngrok") == 0) {
        host = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1011-2006-00-27b9.ngrok.io";
    }
    int r = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &ais);
    if (r != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(r));
        exit(1);
    }

    // connect to server
    int fd = -1;
    for (auto ai = ais; ai && fd < 0; ai = ai->ai_next) {
        fd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, 0);
        if (fd < 0) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        r = connect(fd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen);
        if (r < 0) {
            close(fd);
            fd = -1;
        }
    }
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(ais);

    // 
    printf("Connection established at fd %d\n", fd);
    FILE* f = fdopen(fd, "a+");
    fwrite("!", 1, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    while (true) {
    }
    
}
```

And for the server:

```
#include "helpers.hh"

void handle_connection(int cfd, std::string remote) {
    (void) remote;
    printf("Received incoming connection at cfd: %d\n", cfd);
    usleep(1000000);
    printf("Exiting\n");
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int port = 6162;
    if (argc >= 2) {
        port = strtol(argv[1], nullptr, 0);
        assert(port > 0 && port <= 65535);
    }

    // Prepare listening socket
    int fd = open_listen_socket(port);
    assert(fd >= 0);
    fprintf(stderr, "Listening on port %d...\n", port);

    while (true) {
        struct sockaddr addr;
        socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);

        // Accept connection on listening socket
        int cfd = accept(fd, &addr, &addrlen);
        if (cfd < 0) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Handle connection
        handle_connection(cfd, unparse_sockaddr(&addr, addrlen));
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I think the problem is that my client program was never really able to locate the ngrok-generated address correctly. In my code, I tried to let the client program set the host and port using getaddrinfo, and this time the client just got stuck without even connecting. Perhaps someone should enlighten me on how to use ngrok correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to the typical port forwarding done in the local router, ngrok is not a port forwarder at the transport level (TCP) but it is a request forwarder at the HTTP level.

Thus if the client does a TCP connect to the external ngrok server nothing will be forwarded yet. Only after the client has send the HTTP request the destination will be determined and then this request will be send to the  ngrok connector on the internal machine, which then will initiate the connection to the internal server and forward the request.

Comment: Darn! Thank you, this actually makes a lot of sense. Sorry that I was still quite new to the concepts, as I'm writing these codes actually after taking a system-programming course, not a network course... So, based on your answer, I could send an HTTP request after the connect() from the client-side? Perhaps it might be easier for me to replace ngrok with some tool that allows TCP-level forwarding? What could I use here to make my code work beyond the local network? - uh, maybe I should open a new question or search for this latter question online.

Comment: By the way, I'm using college network so I'm afraid there's no way I can tamper with the routers here :(

Comment: @Macrophage: See for example [Poor man's ngrok with tcp proxy and ssh reverse tunnel](https://dev.to/k4ml/poor-man-ngrok-with-tcp-proxy-and-ssh-reverse-tunnel-1fm) for how to do TCP level forwarding when you have an external server with SSH access.